Using MySqlConnector with Azure Functions
I'm having issues with the latest version of MySqlConnector (2.3.6) and Azure Functions.
I have a new Azure Functions project, .NET 6.0 LTS. As soon as I add the MySqlConnector package via NuGet and debug the project, I encounter this error:

I've tried adding these packages with no success:

Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions
MySqlConnector.Logging.Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Specifying MySqlConnector 2.2.7 (the last version before there is a depency on Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions) works.
I would prefer to use the latest packages where possible.
Any insight on how I can get MySqlConnector 2.3.6 working with Azure Functions?
Edit: I continued development with MySqlConnector 2.2.7 but when I attempted a MySQL connection I get the same error.


Found the answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/665184/azure-function-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-mic
I tried changing to MySql.Data instead of MySqlConnector but still had issues with missing DLLs. Turns out I need to have:
<_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>

in the csproj file.

You can consider switching to isolated function if you want to use MySqlConnector
